# how do I download bluetooth?

Tags: bluez

my blue tooth was working, after the recent software update, bluetooth will not connect. I can see my laptop bluetooth on my mobile phone, but when i search for my blue tooth speaker, it does not show up, it does appear on my mobile.
when i go to bluetooth prefernces, it says bluez daemon is not installed, how do I reinstall?
I tried the various install updates, still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The following command should do the trick.

`sudo apt install bluez`

If it doesn't work, check /var/log/syslog for messages about bluetooth